# How to see syntax errors reported with actual line numbers in the parent script when Perl is embedded within shell script?

Tags: bash, perl, syntax-error, runtime-error, embedded-script

For no justifiable reason at all, I have a pretty substantial Perl script embedded within a Bash function that is being invoked within an [autoenv](https://github.com/kennethreitz/autoenv) `.env` file.

It looks something like this:

```sh
perl='
    $inverse = "\e[7m";
    $invoff  = "\e[27m";
    $bold    = "\e[1m";
    ⋮
'

perl -e "$perl" "$inputfile"
```

I understand that standalone Perl scripts and the `PATH` variable are a thing, and I understand that [Term::ANSIColor](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ANSIColor) is a thing. This is not about that.

**My question is**, if there's a syntax error in the embedded Perl code, how can I get Perl to report the *actual* line number within the parent shell script?

For example, say the `perl=` assignment occurs on line 120 within that file, but there's a syntax error on the 65th line of actual Perl code. I get this:

```
syntax error at -e line 65, near "s/(#.*)$/$comment\1$endcomment/"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

…but I want to see this (the actual line number in the parent script) instead:

```
syntax error at -e line 185, near "s/(#.*)$/$comment\1$endcomment/"
```

#### Things I've tried (that didn't work):

- assigning to `__LINE__`

  - don't even know why I thought that would work; it's not a variable, it's a constant, and you get an error stating the same
- assigning to `$.` (`$INPUT_LINE_NUMBER` with `use English`)

  - I was pretty sure this wasn't going to work anyway, because this is like `NR` in Awk, and this clearly isn't what this is for

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As described in [perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html), you can use the following directive to set the line number and (optionally) the file name of the subsequent line:

```perl
#line 42 "file.pl"
```

This means that you could use

```sh
#!/bin/sh

perl="#line 4 \"$0\""'
warn("test");
'

perl -e "$perl"
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.sh
test at ./a.sh line 4.
```

There's no clean way to avoid hardcoding the line number when using `sh`, but it is possible.

```
#!/bin/sh

script_start=$( perl -ne'if (/^perl=/) { print $.+1; last }' -- "$0" )
perl="#line $script_start \"$0\""'
warn("test");
'

perl -e "$perl"
```

On the other hand, `bash` provides the current line number.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

script_start=$(( LINENO + 2 ))
perl="#line $script_start \"$0\""'
warn("test");
'

perl -e "$perl"
```

Answer (score 4):

There is this useful tidbit in the `perlrun` man page, under the [section for `-x`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-x*), which "tells Perl that the program is embedded in a larger chunk of unrelated text, such as in a mail message."

> All references to line numbers by the program (warnings, errors, ...) will treat the `#!` line as the first line. Thus a warning on the 2nd line of the program, which is on the 100th line in the file will be reported as line 2, not as line 100. **This can be overridden by using the `#line` directive.** ([See Plain Old Comments (Not!)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Plain-Old-Comments-(Not!)) in [`perlsyn`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html))

Based on the bolded statement, adding `#line NNN` (where `NNN` is the actual line number of the parent script where that directive appears) achieves the desired effect:

```sh
perl='#line 120
    $inverse = "\e[7m";
    $invoff  = "\e[27m";
    $bold    = "\e[1m";
    ⋮
'
⋮
```

Comment: This outputs `-e` as the file name. You can pass a second argument to `#line` providing the file name. Place it in double-quotes.

Comment: @ikegami This was such a kludgy script to begin with, I was totally fine with the `-e`, but this is a great tip!